# outline and border in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs, fabricjs2

I am using fabric.js for canvas shapes. but now i have to add border with outline on these shapes like below. How it is possible in fabricjs??. Or do we have any other js library to get same output?

[image]

I want below output:

[image: desired image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a group out of two rectangles? Like so:

```js
var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.StaticCanvas('c');

var rectBack = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 170,
  height: 170,
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  fill: 'rgba(0,0,255,1.0)',
  rx: 2,
  ry: 2
});

var outerMargin = 10
var innerOutlineWidth = 4

var innerOutline = new fabric.Rect({
  width: 170 - outerMargin - innerOutlineWidth/2,
  height: 170 - outerMargin - innerOutlineWidth/2,
  top: outerMargin/2,
  left: outerMargin/2,
  stroke: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.0)',
  fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)',
  strokeWidth: innerOutlineWidth,
  rx: 10,
  ry: 10
});

var group = new fabric.Group([rectBack, innerOutline], {
  left: 0,
  top: 0,
  angle: 0
});

canvas.add(group);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.7.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Any framework you use is going to have some fundamental building blocks you have to piece together to get what you want. So I would not recommend jumping to another one.